# Deploying Azure Function Slot from Visual Studio deploys Production

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

**Short:** How do I create a publish profile in Visual Studio that deploys a deployment slot vs production slot?

**Long:** *That moment when you get a Sev1 call saying that Production is busted and you know that minutes before you just fired off a deployment to your integration deployment slot. Yup that's what just happened to me and for the life of me I can't explain it.*

So we have one deployment slot for our Azure Function app named "Int". When creating the publishing profiles, I simply used the "Create new profile" wizard in Visual Studio and chose "Select Existing" Azure App Service, and then drilled in on the "Int" Deployment Slot. Seemed pretty straight forward. Well doing so causes both Int ***AND*** Production to be deployed. This was certainly unexpected and obviously catastrophic.

After some digging in the Portal I found in the "Overview" section of our Azure Function app there's a "Download publish profile" button. Clicking it for Production as well as for INT yields two separate files with different users, destinationAppUrls, etc. The only thing that was the same between the two was the FTP publishUrl but I assume that the server would route to the appropriate root based on the credentials passed in.

As it stands in spite of the fact that I have two unique publish profiles, one for prod and one for int, deploying either of them updates both production and our deployment slot.

Here's a list of the things I've tried to fix this myself to no avail:

1. Deleted both publishing profiles from Visual Studio and recreated them via the Wizard.
2. Deleted both publishing profiles from Visual Studio and recreated them via the downloaded profiles from the portal.
3. Deleted the INT publishing profile, created a new FTP user in the portal for our INT deployment slot, updated the downloaded profile for INT, then imported it into Visual Studio. <== Honestly I think this was dumb because I don't think VS is using FTP to deploy. I could be wrong though.
4. Ensured AutoSwap is turned off.
5. Used an FTP client to manually login with the publish credentials. Turns out even though Production and Int have different "FTP Deployment Users" logging in as either points at the same location. (This ultimately seems to be the problem)
6. Clicked "Reset publish profile" on the deployment slot and re-downloaded profile.

Other than losing the autoswap feature which I'm not even losing, I suppose one way to work around this would be to create an entirely separate app thus forcing it to work properly. I really want to avoid that if possible though.

Thanks in advance for help here.

Comment: Check this link https://scientistz.com/2018/01/deployment-slots-and-slot-swap-on-azure-app-service-using-visual-studio-and-azure-sdk-part-2/ it might be a help

Comment: do you have autoswap on ? I cant reproduce your problem

Comment: @Thomas Yes. I've ensured autoswap is turned off on the slot.

Comment: VS is using MSDeploy

Comment: Since everything that I've read indicates I shouldn't be having this problem I've also cut a Ticket. Sev C so might be awhile before I hear back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That shouldn't happen, but if I had to guess, you must have the same values for `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` defined in both apps. The former is the storage account where your app content will be saved, and the latter is the share name in that storage account. It's fine for both to share the same `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING`, but if you also share the same `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`, then you'll end up with the odd behavior you're seeing.

Usually when you create the function app through the tooling it should create a new share with a random name for each app. If you deploy using an ARM template or some other method and set these both to be the same you'll run into that behavior.

Comment: YES! Thank you! I have no idea how this happened I created the slot via the Portal and just went with the defaults. I had no idea that setting was tied to this.