# Azure Functions: Deploying to stage slot also deploys to production slot

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I have an Azure Function App v3 running a Node.js app that has a production and a stage slot. It gets deployed to from GitHub using an Action created in Deployment Center. I have one deploy action for prod and one for stage, and have verified that the prod deploy is not running.

When the stage deploy Action runs it is successful, but the code ends up in *both* the stage and production environments.

"Auto-swap enabled" is Off. I have not manually triggered a swap, either.

For `stg` the YAML looks like this:

```
- name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
  uses: Azure/functions-action@v1.3.1
  id: fa
  with:
    app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
    package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE_STAGE }}
    slot-name: 'stg'
```

For `production` the YAML looks like this:

```
- name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
  uses: Azure/functions-action@v1.3.1
  id: fa
  with:
    app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
    package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
    slot-name: 'production'
```

These both appear to match what is auto-generated by Deployment Center for each of the slots.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that Configuration > Application settings > `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` on the `stg` slot was identical to the `production` slot.

So I believe this meant that deliverables from either deploy were being dropped into the same storage location. So stage deploys were effectively overwriting prod code!

I think the `stg` slot was created using the Portal, so I guess this is just something to look out for.

Based on what I've learned today, I'd recommend making sure that every slots' `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` is unique.

What I don't know right now is whether that setting should also be a "Deployment slot setting". It kind of seems like it should, but maybe that will make a swap not work properly?

I wouldn't have found this without https://stackoverflow.com/a/50824960/12031280 by @ahmelsayed

Comment: It doesn't allow you to set it as "Deployment slot setting" and it makes sense because WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE is used somehow to point at the files deployed for that specific slot, eg stage. So if you made it sticky, a swap operation would not swap the project files as well, so what you deployed on stage would always remain on stage.